# AMCL cannot publish a pose or update the transform. Please set the initial pose

Tags: navigation, ros2, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a ROS2 n00b trying to learn navigation2. I have a lot of experience with ROS1's navigation stack but am having basic issues with navigation2. I'm running ROS2 galactic built from source on an NVidia Jetson Xavier NX running Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS bionic. I'm currently have an issue where AMCL doesn't publish the map->odom transform. This message gets printed every 2 seconds:

`AMCL cannot publish a pose or update the transform. Please set the initial pose...`

I'm not sure what AMCL is asking for here. How can I set an initial pose if map->odom isn't defined? I have an initial pose of 0, 0, 0, 0 set in my config and what seems to be a valid map. One thing that confuses me is why the map_server only publishes the map once when it launches and never again. Could this be part of the problem?

I'm launching navigation2 with their localization bring up launch file: nav2_bringup/launch/localization_launch.py

rqt_graph:

[image: image description]

tf tree:

[image: image description]

Link to launch file in question:

https://github.com/frc-88/tj2_ros/blob/dev/ros2/tj2_navigation/launch/localization.py

Full terminal output:

```
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/tj2/.ros/log/2022-05-23-15-43-07-215734-porygon2-18955
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [map_server-1]: process started with pid [18963]
[INFO] [amcl-2]: process started with pid [18964]
[INFO] [lifecycle_manager-3]: process started with pid [18965]
[lifecycle_manager-3] [INFO] [1653334989.312059616] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Creating
[lifecycle_manager-3] [INFO] [1653334989.362775040] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Creating and initializing lifecycle service clients
[lifecycle_manager-3] [INFO] [1653334989.473732992] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Starting managed nodes bringup...
[lifecycle_manager-3] [INFO] [1653334989.473970336] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Configuring map_server
[map_server-1] [INFO] [1653334989.629669088] [map_server]: 
[map_server-1]  map_server lifecycle node launched. 
[map_server-1]  Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[map_server-1]  See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[map_server-1] [INFO] [1653334989.630390592] [map_server]: Creating
[map_server-1] [INFO] [1653334989.646481792] [map_server]: Configuring
[map_server-1] [INFO] [map_io]: Loading yaml file: /home/tj2/ros2_ws/install/tj2_navigation/share/tj2_navigation/maps/map_1653284131.yaml
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: resolution: 0.05
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: origin[0]: -4.07
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: origin[1]: -6
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: origin[2]: 0
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: free_thresh: 0.25
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: occupied_thresh: 0.65
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: mode: trinary
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: negate: 0
[map_server-1] [INFO] [map_io]: Loading image_file: /home/tj2/ros2_ws/install/tj2_navigation/share/tj2_navigation/maps/map_1653284131.pgm
[map_server-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: Read map /home/tj2/ros2_ws/install/tj2_navigation/share/tj2_navigation/maps/map_1653284131.pgm: 206 X 187 map @ 0.05 m/cell
[amcl-2] [INFO] [1653334989.724978304] [amcl]: 
[amcl-2]    amcl lifecycle node launched. 
[amcl-2]    Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[amcl-2]    See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[amcl-2] [INFO] [1653334989.725556160] [amcl]: Creating
[lifecycle_manager-3] [INFO] [1653334989.760930624] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Configuring amcl
[amcl-2] [INFO] [1653334989.824301664] [amcl]: Configuring
[amcl-2] [INFO] [1653334989.826404096] [amcl]: initTransforms
[amcl-2] [INFO] [1653334989.899745056] [amcl]: initPubSub
[amcl-2] [INFO] [1653334989.917563232] [amcl]: Subscribed to map topic.
[lifecycle_manager-3] [INFO] [1653334989.936369088] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Activating map_server
[map_server-1] [INFO] [1653334989.938350944] [map_server]: Activating
[map_server-1] [INFO] [1653334989.941107424] [map_server]: Creating bond (map_server) to lifecycle manager.
[amcl-2] [INFO] [1653334989.941796352] [amcl]: Received a 206 X 187 map @ 0.050 m/pix
[lifecycle_manager-3] [INFO] [1653334990.065884288] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Server map_server connected with bond.
[lifecycle_manager-3] [INFO] [1653334990.066133888] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Activating amcl
[amcl-2] [INFO] [1653334990.067579520] [amcl]: Activating
[amcl-2] [INFO] [1653334990.067867424] [amcl]: Creating bond (amcl) to lifecycle manager.
[amcl-2] [INFO] [1653334990.119759712] [amcl]: createLaserObject
[lifecycle_manager-3] [INFO] [1653334990.188636608] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Server amcl connected with bond.
[lifecycle_manager-3] [INFO] [1653334990.189697792] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Managed nodes are active
[lifecycle_manager-3] [INFO] [1653334990.189789920] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Creating bond timer...
[amcl-2] [INFO] [1653334990.948295360] [amcl_rclcpp_node]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser' at time 1653334989.853 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[amcl-2] [WARN] [1653334991.909636192] [amcl]: AMCL cannot publish a pose or update the transform. Please set the initial pose...
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401185/amcl-cannot-publish-a-pose-or-update-the-transform.-please-set-the-initial-pose.../) by [Woz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33545/woz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2022-05-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AMCL wants to know where the robot is located in the map. That will be its initial position and from which it starts `map->odom` transform.

You can do this by using RViz2 and choosing `2D Pose Estimate` or by directly publishing on a topic called `initial_pose` or `initial_position` something like that. Check your topic list to find the exact topic and message type.

EDIT: There is a third way of setting the initial pose, by setting it as a parameter. Except you need to change `set_initial_pose` to true [in line 18](https://github.com/frc-88/tj2_ros/blob/8f3df133e1548edbe4a960a0c7e8f06981d15cf0/tj2_navigation/config/navigation.yaml#L18) of your config file.

You can find the list of parameters for AMCL [here](https://navigation.ros.org/configuration/packages/configuring-amcl.html) with the description of `set_initial_pose` as:

```
Description
    Causes AMCL to set initial pose from the initial_pose* parameters instead of waiting for the initial_pose message.
```

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2022-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Woz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33545/woz/) on 2022-05-27**:
Setting the `set_initial_pose` to true fixed my original issue. I have a new issue now, AMCL is crashing with no error message. It seems to crash when it resamples. I've tried a few different config files with the same result:
`[ERROR] [amcl-2]: process has died [pid 14225, exit code -11, cmd '/home/tj2/ros2_galactic/install/nav2_amcl/lib/nav2_amcl/amcl --ros-args -r __node:=amcl --params-file /tmp/tmp1agefuly -r /tf:=tf -r /tf_static:=tf_static'].`
Is there a way to get more debug information than that? I tried to build with debug but it didn't seem to change anything:
`colcon build --symlink-install --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug --packages-select nav2_amcl --allow-overriding nav2_amcl`

**Comment by [Woz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33545/woz/) on 2022-05-28**:
Ok, I've fixed my issue with AMCL crashing. I'm on galactic and changed this parameter from:
`robot_model_type: nav2_amcl::OmniMotionModel`

to

`robot_model_type: omnidirectional`